# convert javascript variable to C# variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to use a javascript variable to pass as a parameter to my class constructor in C#.

How can I translate the javascript variable ID to C# such that I am able to pass the value on `User.IsOnLeave`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ID;
  var dateToEvaluate;

  function convertVariable() {
    *if (User.IsOnLeave(***ID***, dateToEvaluate)) {...}*
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't access JS variables directly from C#, because JS is client-side and C# is server-side. You can make a controller action and make an AJAX request to it with those parameters. Like this:

JS:

```
var id;
var dataToEvaluate;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SomeController/SomeAction',
    data: { id: id, dataToEvaluate: dataToEvaluate },
    success: function(data) {
        // do what you have to do with the result of the action
    }
});
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string id, string dataToEvaluate)
{
     // some processing here
     return <probably a JsonResult or something that fits your needs>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way ***(IMO, the only way)*** of working with your C# code inside your JavaScript code is to make `Ajax` calls.

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option  is to just render the value to a hidden textbox or dom element, then have javascript access the field.

For example

```
<input type="hidden" value="set from c#" id="myValue" />
```

in javascript

```
var dateToEvaluate = document.getElemenetById("myValue").value;
```

Or if you Javascript is in the same file as your HTML. You could just say in javascript:

```
var dateToEvaluate = @myValue;
```

assuming razor syntax

Comment: why the down vote? Similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript/4599403#4599403 has over 177 up votes

Comment: I would assume it's because the OP is trying to get a JS value into C# code, and not the other way around as you have demonstrated.