# MVC 3 Razor how to make complex javascript conditional?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got this multi-line javascript snippet:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("ReconBases")', 
          { modelId: selectedModelId },
          function(selectItems) { 
            buildDropDown('#SelectedReconId', selectItems); 
          });
```

I want to conditionally add this script to the page based on a view model variable, like this:

```
@if ( Model.GetBases )
{
  <snippet above>
}
```

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and the right syntax for doing this?  I've tried using @: and Html.Raw, but I can't seem to get the right format for it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using razor within javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Output code inside a conditional in Razor must be surrounded by HTML tags such as `<div></div>` (this "flags" it as output, and not more C# code).

If no particular tag suits your needs you can use the special `<text></text>` that are Razor specific. These are **NOT** outputted during rendering.

```
@if ( Model.GetBases )
{
  <text>
    <snippet above>
  </text>
}
```

This also applies to `for`, `foreach`, etc.

Answer (score 10):

You can also make conditon of c# with javascript some code snippet here.

**Multi-line JavaScript Code**

Use `<text></text>`

```
@if ( Model.SomeProp == true)
{
  <text>
    <Your javaScript Multi-line  code>
  </text>
}
```

**Single-line JavaScript code**

Use `@:`

```
@if ( Model.SomeProp == true)
{  
    @:<Your javaScript single code>  
}
```

Comment: If Model.SomePop type is Boolean don't compare the value to true, just use the property as the if statement. if(Model.SomeProp) {