# What is the @ symbol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/refactoring-javascript-into-pure-functions-to-make-code-more-readable-and-mainta and I don't understand the answer since the user uses an @ symbol in a way I've never seen before. What does it do when attached to the if keyword? Can you attach it to other keywords?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a JavaScript thing. It's a symbol used by whatever templating system that answer was referring to. Note that the `<script>` element has type `text/html`, which will prevent browsers from paying any attention to its contents.

Some other JavaScript code will find that script and fetch its `innerHTML` in order to merge the template with some data to create ... well whatever that template makes.

Comment: The templating system in question is Razor in .Net MVC3

Answer (score 3):

@:  syntax in Razor

Said by @StriplingWarrior at [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

It is razor code, not javascript, if you are interested in razor check:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Razor syntax starts code blocks with a @ character and does not require explicit closing of the code-block.