# How do I use Razor values in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using razor within javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

I would like to place a siimple value from the model on a razor page and use it as a constant value in a javascript function.  i.e.

```
<script> var myValue = @Model.myRecord.Count();</script>
```

so that myValue = the record count in my model. I am using myRecord.Count as an example, it could be any value from my model.

Is this possible?

TIA
J

OK I stumbled across the following solution:

```
<script> var myValue = @(Model.myRecord.Count())</script>
```

Just putting inthe extra brackets helped.

Comment: YES IT IS POSSIBLE. Are you facing any errors ?

Comment: That code should work. What is the error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, just make sure to properly encode it. For example you could JSON encode the entire model itself:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    // at this stage the model javascript variable represents the JSON encoded
    // value of your server side model so that you can access all it's properties:
    alert(model.length);
</script>
```

or:

```
alert(model[2].Foo.Bar);
```

or whatever.

But if you only care about the number of elements inside the model (if this model represents a collection):

```
var count = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Count()));
alert(count);
```

Comment: Solved my issue, i had to change Encode to Serialize :  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.data)), works perfect, thanks

Comment: This only works if you embed the JS into the .cshtml file, by the way. The answer could make that more clear.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure this is in a Razor file:

```
<script> var myValue = @Model.myRecord.Count();</script>
```

If it is in just a js file, the Razor engine won't run that code at all.

Comment: int's are probably ok but other datatypes will fail with it.