# ASP.net MVC insert JavaScript function result in view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
<div>javascript:processData(Model.Property)</div>
```

, where "`processData`" is a function that returns a string. How can this be done?

(This obviously is not working, it just returns the string "`javascript:processData(Model.Property)`".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the javascript method on jquery document `ready` and set the result to that div using [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```
@model YourSomeModelWithThatProperty
<div id="thatDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
       var thatDataString=processData("@Model.Property");
       $("#thatDiv").html(thatDataString);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, I know about this method...the problem is much more complex and I have tried to simplify it in my question, finally, if I can't find a solution I'll go with this method. But still, I think there is a simple way to do this. or isn't it? Can't I just call somehow javascript function inside the div? Anyway, your answer is the closest to what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processData(property) {
    // all kinds of stuff...
    // return result;
}
</script>
...
<input type="button" onClick="return processData(<%: Model.Property %>); />
```

If you're using Razor syntax, replace `<%: Model.Property %>` with `@Model.Property`.

As for displaying the result, use the javascript to put the value somewhere on the page (such as the text of an `<a>` element or an `alert`).

Comment: I need just to display the result, not to invoke it on an event

Comment: @SandraS. so were you now able to use Jacob's code to resolve your code display or not?

Comment: @SandraS. did my edit answer your question? If not, please clarify.

Comment: nothing seems to work...maybe I wasn't clear enough...I'll try to simplify even more:<div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function doTest() {
                        return "Str_to_Output";
                    }
                    doTest();
                 </script> How can I display "Str_to_Output" inside the div?

Answer (score 0):

Read the following question :
[Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript?rq=1)

You need razor text markers:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx