# MVC 4 model in javascripts code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to do this if statement below with a value in a model object in razor view.
I do not know how to do it though...
Anyone has any idea?

```
<script> 
if (@Model.projects.Count == 1) {
    var prj_id = document.getElementById('prj_id');
    prj_id.selectedIndex = 1;
    LoadOwner();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use Ajax or Json for this

Comment: This question is dublicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript

Comment: Your code seems fine. Just make sure that @(Model.projects.Count) is never null so that the generated HTML doesn't have a javascript typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste model variable in javascript code you need something like this:

```
<script> 

var count = '@Model.projects.Count';
if (count == 1) {
    var prj_id = document.getElementById('prj_id');
    prj_id.selectedIndex = 1;
    LoadOwner();
  }
</script>
```

Or like this, depending what is suitable for you:

```
@if (Model.projects.Count == 1) {
  <script> 
    var prj_id = document.getElementById('prj_id');
    prj_id.selectedIndex = 1;
    LoadOwner();
  </script>
}
```