# How do I use html and escape razor inside a razor foreach?

Tags: c#, html, razor, escaping

How do I build my html inside the razor foreach? I get "Cannot resolve tbody" inside the foreach.

My code:

```
function loadNyhedsbrevTable() {
    var tbody = "";

    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').empty();
    @foreach (string n in ViewBag.NyhedsbrevListe)
    { 
        tbody = '<tr><td>' + n + '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').append(tbody);
}
```

Do I need something like this?

`<not razor> tbody = '<tr><td>' + @n + <not razor>'</td></tr>'`;

Comment: Maybe I can't use foreach and should only use for instead?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly HTML, it's javascript. So check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript  For pure HTML see no troubles...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I hope this help

```
@foreach (string n in ViewBag.NyhedsbrevListe)
{ 
    @:tbody = '<tr><td>' + n + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Source:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: This workes too. When I tested it the first time I must have had another error.

Comment: I will accept yours instead because you answered first and it's two lines less. It might even be more best pratice, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix javascript and razor like that. razor gets processed server side while rendering the page, javascript is a client-side srcipt.

What you would need to do is render a valid piece of javascript code. Assuming you want to append a row for each item in the loop, then something like this should work:

```
function loadNyhedsbrevTable() {
    var tbody = "";

    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').empty();

    @foreach (string n in ViewBag.NyhedsbrevListe)
    { 
        <text>
            tbody += '<tr><td>@(n)</td></tr>';
        </text>
    }

    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').append(tbody);
}
```

This would result in the following rendered output, for example:

```
function loadNyhedsbrevTable() {
    var tbody = "";

    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').empty();

    tbody += '<tr><td>one</td></tr>';
    tbody += '<tr><td>two</td></tr>';
    tbody += '<tr><td>three</td></tr>';

    $('#NyhedsbrevTable tbody').append(tbody);
}
```

Comment: I am trying the same, where I use <text> to switch back to content mode. I have a error im trying to fix at the moment, but i think it's something else. By the way, don't we need a `@` before the `n`in the loop, so we use the value from razor?

Comment: @radbyx: Yes, well spotted. I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok im testing it now.

Comment: It works wow! I had to change `string` to `var` because the list was IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, and I had to add `.Text` to `n`, but that was my mistakes. :)