# Razor template containing page parts that mustache will render on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

My page contains parts that will render on the client.

The problem I'm having is that razor does not render the parts as I expect them to. For example:

```
<script type="x-tmpl-mustache" id="filterTemplate">
        <img id="showFilter" src="~/Content/Image/arrow.png" />
</script>
```

Will not render the `~` sign, only when I place img outside of the script tags will it do as expected.

This is published in different application paths so I need razor to figure out what `~` is and replace it with the application path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Url.Content` helper which will correctly resolve the path relative to the application root:

```
<script type="x-tmpl-mustache" id="filterTemplate">
        <img id="showFilter" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Image/arrow.png")' />
</script>
```