# Baloon location on map is incorrect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, maps, yandex-maps

I put yandex map (russian analogue of google map) on my view. But but baloon's location does not match the coordinates!

Here is the code:

**Example #1** *- baloons display not correct*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap,
        myPlacemark;

    function init() {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        });

        @foreach (var person in Model)
        {
            <text>
        console.log('Service = @person.ServiceName, x = @person.CoordinateX, y = @person.CoordinateY');

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([@(person.CoordinateX), @(person.CoordinateY)], {
            hintContent: '@(person.ServiceName)',
            balloonContent: '@(person.CoordinateX), @(person.CoordinateY)'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            </text>
        }
    }
</script>
```

But if I change it to constants (not in loop "foreach"), everything is normal:

**Example #2** *- baloons display correct*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap,
        myPlacemark;

    function init() {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        });

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.871030, 37.658510], {
            hintContent: 'hint',
            balloonContent: 'content'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.782392, 37.614924], {
            hintContent: 'hint',
            balloonContent: 'content'
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    }
</script>
```

***NOTE:*** in Example #1 in console I get rigth values:

Service = something1, x = 55,87103, y = 37,65851

Service = something2, x = 55,782392, y = 37,614924

but baloon's location does not match the coordinates:

[Incorrect baloons positions on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYGeu.png)

Comment: Can you bring an example of coordinates you pass to `ymaps.Placemark`?

Comment: Example of coordinates: 1) CoordinateX = 55.871030, CoordinateY = 37.658510; 2)  CoordinateX = 55.782392, CoordinateY = 37.614924

Comment: I don't know ASP.Net, but swift search made me suspicious about `<text>...</text>` part. Try to remove `<text>` "tag" around placemark creation code (in `@foreach`).

Comment: BTW, if you have a link to a page with the problem, please post it here, so I can look into it more closely.

Comment: Also, make sure that your template don't produce numbers with **commas** in coordinates instead of points.

Comment: I use <text> tags because of this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript I get a lot of errors when remove it.

Comment: Kirill Dmitrenko, you're rigth: the problem was I use commas instead points! Solved.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found out that the problem was in the way ASP.Net outputs the numbers in the posted code snippets. They're printed into JS code with floating **commas** instead of points.