# ASP Net Razor code in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I'm sure that i'm having problems with quotes in function. How can i put my razor code in my js function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetSelectedValue() {
        var e = document.getElementById('Analitycs');
        var eValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var div = document.getElementById('addedBody');
        switch (eValue) {
            case "1": div.innerHTML += '<text><label>Контрагент</label><select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="7" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@Model.Partners, "Name", "Name"))" asp-for="FilterModel.PartnerName"><option value="">Выберите контрагента</option></select></text>'
                break
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not to build the list outside and then set the variable?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript#4599403

Comment: @William-H-M Yes, it is an option but i'm not sure anyway how to create the variable putting razor syntax