# Show TempData message in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-core

I would like to show popup message if there is an error on the page but somehow jquery doesn't show anything.

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         if(@TempData["Error"].ToString() != null)
         {
             alert("Message 1");
         } else {
             alert("Message 2");
         }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: is this `mvc` related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Razor within JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` is not the correct method name, the correct method name is `toString()`

Comment: thanks, Nithi but I can't use toString because after @ it must be a c# code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this way

```
    var val = '@Html.Raw((string)TempData["ErrorMessage"])';
    if(val != "")
    {
        alert(val);
    }
```