# Dynamically read of inputs Razor MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have problem with aggregating inputs from dynamically created combo boxes.
In my view .cshtml I'm creating multiple  elements with multiple choices as 
and I'm trying to set onClick trigger to this element like in snippet:

```
 @foreach (var value in values)
  {
     <option onclick="@UpdateSelectedFilters(item.DisplayName, value)" value="@value" >@value</option>
  }
```

But unfortunately this function "@UpdateSelectedFilters()" is executed on render of element, not on  click event like i want to.

Answer (score 1):

İf your project not Blazor You cant use @ at onClick event.

you can create a javascript function like:

```
function UpdateSelectedFilters(displayname, value){
    ...some code 
}
```

You can check the answer below

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599403/8193695)

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateSelectedFilters` is a js function,so you don't need to use `@` before it.Try to use

```
<option onclick="UpdateSelectedFilters(@item.DisplayName, @value)" value="@value" >@value</option>
```

so that you can pass C# data to js function.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to javascript wasn't enough, model should be binded too in for example in asp-items

```
<select id="@name" class="form-control col-lg-3" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top:10px" name="@name" asp-items="@options" onchange="UpdateSelectedFilters(this.name,this.value)">
```