# I want to read an array from the controller and use it in an Html script

Tags: c#, html, viewdata

I'd love some help here :)
I'm trying to read the array I have in the controller into a variable in the script and use it.. Can someone help me please?

I'm actually trying to make an array of the names of the recipes that I already have in another list
[This is what I have on the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t2Yd.png)

Then I need this list to use it in HTML and therefore -
[This is what I have in the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zl8d.png)

As you understand, it doesn't work for me (by the way, when I enter directly in the script like this: var NAME=["---","---"...] it does work..)

I'm new to the subject, so I'm getting very confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: You're outputting a C# array into a JavaScript context: you need to serialize it to JSON first. You nearly had that in your commented-out code, but you needed an `@` before your `Html.Raw`. You may also find this answer helpful, particularly the last update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599403/120955