# Problems with a jquery line when using Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have have following line that is working correctly:

```
 html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name + "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer + "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate + "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + "</td>"
```

When I try this I get my JSON displayed.

```
html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name + "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer + "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate + "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + "</td><td>" +  @Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit") | @Html.ActionLink("x", "Inactive", new { @class = "deleteLink" }) + "</td>"
```

I also recieve a bunch of errors such as:

- 'return' statement outside of function'
- Expected ';'
- Syntax error
- Expected identifier or string

Am I doing something wrong here?

This is the complete function:

```
 result.forEach(function (goalcard) {
                                $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").append(
                                    $('<tr/>', {
                                        click: function() {
                                            id = goalcard.Id;
                                            var url = '@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI", new { id = "__id__"})';
                                            window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);


                                        },
                                        // steg Create a row for each result 
                                        html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name + "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer + "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate + "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + "</td><td>" +  @(Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit")) | @(Html.ActionLink("x", "Inactive", new { @class = "deleteLink" })) + "</td>"
                                    }));
                            });
                            $('#GoalcardSearchResult tbody').trigger("update");                                
                            $("#GoalcardSearchResult").tablesorter();
                        });

                        return false;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, I'd definitely say you're doing something wrong if you're getting those errors :D Although you're not showing the relevant code, so that doesn't help us help you much.

Comment: Updated, If I remove the razor stuff everything works fine :S

Comment: You can't have razor syntax directly within javascript. You will need to use pseudo <text> or @: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045308/razor-syntax-and-javascript/4047382#4047382

Comment: Could you give me an example? I dont know where to use @:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
 "</td><td>" + @(Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit")) | @(Html.ActionLink("x", "Inactive", new { @class = "deleteLink" })) + "</td>"
```

generates

```
"</td><td>" + <a href="/Examination/CertificationAnnouncements/Edit">&#196;ndra</a> | <a href="/Examination/CertificationAnnouncements/Inactive?class=deleteLink">x</a> + "</td>"
```

Note that generated anchors do not have string identifiers (' or "), so you get errors. You should change code to

```
 "</td><td>" + '@(Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit")) | @(Html.ActionLink("x", "Inactive", new { @class = "deleteLink" }))' + "</td>"
```