# Javascript window.location not working in MVC3

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that is rendered via an `ActionResult` called `EntityIndex` that takes `int id` as a parameter and loads that entity.

On this view a user can select from a dropdown other related entities and the view should reload by sending the selected ID from the dropdown to the same Action `EntityIndex` with the new `ID`.

I'm using a jQuery change event on the dropdown to navigate and reload the page:

```
$("#RelatedEntity").change(function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("EntityIndex", new {id = ""})' + '/' + $(this).val();
});
```

This is the Action

```
public ActionResult EntityIndex(int id) {
    ... gets entity by id here ...
    return View(model);
}
```

The action works fine when hit but the jQuery line above is failing with an error:

```
http://localhost:1798/Entity/EntityIndex/@Url.Action("EntityIndex", new {id = ""})/539
```

For some reason the `window.location` firing the `@Url.Action` is treating the action as a string and not an action to navigate to... what is wrong with the `Url.Action` that keeps it from behaving correctly?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045308/razor-syntax-and-javascript

Comment: @JanAagaard It isn't a dupe, this is more to do with routing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JQuery is ever-so-slightly *off*. Using the default route and specifying no ID will generate:

> /controller/action/

So all you need to do is put your value on the end. Try this:

```
$("#RelatedEntity").change(function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("EntityIndex")' + $(this).val();
});
```

Should give you (assuming value is 23):

> /controller/action/23

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, using that I navigate to http://localhost:1798/Entity/EntityIndex/@Url.Action(%22EntityIndex%22)539 which doesn't give me the big ugly IIS error that I was getting, but more of a 'what the hell is this string parameter?' type error

Comment: Ah hang on, are you trying to use this in an external JS file or something other than a Razor view?

Comment: Yes! This JS is in a separate file Entity.js and is inside the document.ready section and is referenced into the view with the script tag

Comment: Ah then you can't use Razor syntax in an external file, what you'll have to do is either store the Razor generated link inside a hidden input OR call a function in your external JS file from your view and pass it the Razor generated link as a parameter to the function, then store that globally in a variable in your JS file. Using `@URl....` in a JS file is literally just using a string with the @ in :)

Comment: Hahahaha don't worry, happens to the best of us :). I'm sure I've tried and failed that before!

Comment: Thanks, I put it back inside my partial (new partial form where it was before - that's the reason why I moved it to begin with) works like a charm with original code now :-)