# How to Insert an Inline Razor Expression into Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {

    var count = $("#tblUploadDocs").prop('rows').length;
    count += 1;

    alert(count);
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input type="file" name="files" id="file' + count + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td>Bu dilden</td>';

    html += '<tr>';
    alert(html);

}
</script>
```

I am trying to insert the following line into the script, but could not achieve the desired result:

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlFromLanguage1", ViewBag.Languages as SelectList)</td>
```

I tried both  and @: but could not make it work. I am looking forward to hearing to a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<text>` pseudo-element, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045308/razor-syntax-and-javascript/4047382#4047382), to force the razor compiler back into content mode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
  <text>
    var count = $("#tblUploadDocs").prop('rows').length;
    count += 1;

    alert(count);
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input type="file" name="files" id="file' + count + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td>Bu dilden</td>';

    html += '<tr>';
    alert(html);

  </text>
}
</script>
```