# How to display viewbag elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to call the Method in Jquery's Append Method ?

I have the HTML code in which I use the append method() on click of a button. 
I want to append the HTML with viewbag data using loop. 
here is my code , is that right ?

```
        <html>
        <body>
        <div class="row-fluid" id="MyCode">
        </div>
        <button name="AddCode"></button>
        </body>
        </html>

         <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function ()
           {

               $('#AddCode').click(function () {

                     $('#MyCode').append("<di ><div class='span2'>" +

                      //I want to call the function here... 
                     AddDivs()
           );

        });

 function AddDivs()
 {
  var ht="";
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LocationList)
{
 ht += "<div id='"+item.Id+"_"+item.Name+"'></div>";
  }
  }

 });
 </script>
```

Its showing undefined.

Comment: You are not closing the div tags in append method!

Comment: its kind of pseudo code... its working in my code... I get the error regarding the data. see in my comment...

Comment: A quick google search of "razor syntax javascript" shows two stackoverflow [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript) that should [help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045308/razor-syntax-and-javascript). The words might be different but the problem is the same.

Comment: Then r u sure the viewBags isn't empty!! Don't you receive compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

Change `foreach` loop with following:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.LocationList)
{
    // these lines are client codes that is in server codes
    <text>ht += "<div id='" + @item.Id + "_" + @item.Name + "'></div>";</text>
}
```

if you dont write your js codes in `<text>`, razor assume that `ht` is an server variable.

Comment: Tried , Error comes as VileParle is not defined Error is - >   function AddDivs()
            {
                var ht= "";
              
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + VileParle  + "'></div>";
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + SakiNaka  + "'></div>";
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + Bhivandi  + "'></div>";
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + Andheri  + "'></div>";
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + Santacruz  + "'></div>";
                     ht += "<div id=_'" + Borivali  + "'></div>";

             
                return ht;
            }

Comment: cant assign the values to ht, <text> is important ?

Answer (score 0):

script tag must be inside of body tag

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
             ...                
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```