# Javascript variable contains asp.net mvc razor code instead of value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            @{
                string area = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null ? 
                    ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString().ToLower() : 
                    string.Empty;
            }


        var area = "@area";

</script>
```

and my Google Chrome, if I call `area` variable in console, displays like:

`" != null ? ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString().ToLower() : """`

which is a part of C# code ...

Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem when you are trying to use the razor inside script blocks.

There is an amazing answer of the issue here: 
[Razor Syntax and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045308/razor-syntax-and-javascript/4047382#4047382)

So you should either modified your code to

```
 @{
    string area = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null ? 
                  ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString().ToLower() : 
                  string.Empty;
  }
<script type="text/javascript">               
    var area = "@area";    
</script>
```

Or to wrap your code in a  pseudo block (or @: if you are using the newer version of MVC)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            @{
              <text>  string area = ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null ? 
                    ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString().ToLower() : 
                    string.Empty;</text>
            }    

        var area = "@area";    
</script>
```